# Logarithmic and exponential functions

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

This is an exercise from the book "Logaritmos" by Elon Lages Lima.

A bijection $E:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is called an *exponential funtion* when its inverse $F:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a logarithmic function. 
Prove that the bijetion $E:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ is an exponential function if, and only if:

a) $E$ is increasing, i.e., $x < y \Rightarrow E(x) < E(y)$;

b) $E(x+y) = E(x)\cdot E(y)$.

---

Additional info: in this book, the logarithmic function is defined as a function $L: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

i) $x< y \Rightarrow L(x) < L(y)$;

ii) $L(xy) = L(x) + L(y), \forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}^+$

---

I managed to prove the first implication, i.e., that $E = F^{-1} \Rightarrow E$ has properties a) and b).

I've been stuck with the second implication.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of *any* strictly increasing function exists and is strictly increasing; this general fact shows that (a) implies (i).

If (b) holds, and $F=E^{-1}$, then applying (b) with $F(x)$ and $F(y)$ in place of $x$ and $y$ yields
$$
E(F(x)+F(y)) = E(F(x))\cdot E(F(y)) = x\cdot y.
$$
Now taking $F$ of both sides gives
$$
F(x) + F(y) = F(E(F(x)+F(y))) = F(x\cdot y)
$$
which is (ii).

Comment: We should show that if a) and b) hold, then $E = F^{-1}$.
We can't assume that E and F are inverse.

Comment: I think my understanding of the logic is correct; think about it again.

Comment: I have some difficulties in understanding why you have assumed that $E = F^{-1}$.
In my understanding, it should be shown that $(\Rightarrow)$  $E = F^{-1}$ implies that a) and b) hold, and $(\Leftarrow)$ if a) and b) hold, then $E = F^{-1}$.

Could you you clarify you assumption that $E = F^{-1}$

Comment: @KirkLand It is given for both the $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$ implications that $E$ is a bijection. So $E$ has an inverse. This answer gives that inverse the name $F.$ The answer does not assume (as you apparently did) that merely naming a function $F$ gives it any special properties (such as being a logarithm).

Comment: @DavidK, thanks. Just checking if I understood: it's known that $E$ has an inverse. We show that $E^{-1}$ has properties (i) and (ii). Thus, $E^{-1}$ must be a logarithmic function. Hence, $E$ is exponential. Is that the core of the reasoning?

Comment: That's the idea.

Answer (score 0):

$(\Rightarrow)$ We assume that $E$ is exponential, i.e., $E = F^{-1}$. We must show that a) and b) hold.

Let's show a), i.e., $E$ is increasing. Take $x_1, x_2, \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x_1 < x_2$. Assume that $E(x_1) \geq E(x_2)$.

Since $F$ is increasing and $E(x_1), E(x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $F(E(x_1)) \geq F(E(x_2))$. Since $E= F^{-1}$ by assumption, it follows that $x_1 \geq x_2$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $E(x_1) < E(x_2)$, i.e., a) holds.

Now let's prove that b) hold.

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R} = Im (F)$. Thus, there exists $x_0$ and $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $F(x_0) = x$ and $F(y_0)= y$ (by surjectivity of $F$).

Adding the two equations we have $F(x_0) +F(y_0) = x + y$.
Since $F$ is logarithmic,  $F(x_0) +F(y_0) = F(x_0 \cdot y_0) = x + y$

Applying $E$, it follows that $E(x+y) = E(F(x_0 \cdot y_0)) = x_0 \cdot y_0$.

However, $F(x_0) = x \Leftrightarrow E(x) = x_0 $ and $F(y_0) = y \Leftrightarrow E(y) = y_0$.

Thus,  $E(x+y)= x_0 \cdot y_0 \Rightarrow E(x + y) = E(x) \cdot E(y)$.

Therefore , b) holds.